# Why Importing gmail contacts using Omnicontacts takes only 99 contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am using omnicontacts to import contacts from gmail. But It takes only 99 contacts not all.
Here is my code

```
def contacts_callback
  @contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
  @contacts.each do |contact|
  contact1 = current_user.contacts.new
  contact1.name = contact[:name]
  contact1.email = contact[:email]
  contact1.group = "Others"
  contact1.save(:validate => false)
end
  redirect_to "/contact"
end
```

I can't figure out problem. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the max_contacts option in your initializer:

```
importer :gmail, "xxx", "yyy", :max_results => 1000
```

I have just updated the README to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :)

I went to lib/omnicontacts/importer/gmail.rb

```
  def initialize *args
    super *args
    @auth_host = "accounts.google.com"
    @authorize_path = "/o/oauth2/auth"
    @auth_token_path = "/o/oauth2/token"
    @scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
    @contacts_host = "www.google.com"
    @contacts_path = "/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
    @max_results =  (args[3] && args[3][:max_results]) || 100
  end
```

And I just change @max_results 100 to 500. Now its working